Unable to connect to sqllocaldb with nestjs
I have an application built using nestjs which apparently works fine against SQL Server Express or other versions in production.
Locally, I am trying to make it work with sqllocaldb but to no avail. I have used configuration of the form
const config = { connectionString: "<my connection string>" };

const config = { server: "localhost", /* with and without port: 1433 */ /* ... other details */ };

const config = { server: "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB", /* ... other details */ };

Neither has worked so far, with different errors of forms

unable to connect to localhost:1433

or

ERROR in Connection getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localdb) {

Is it possible that the combination is doomed to fail?

i think one needs tcpip for nestjs but localdb works with named pipes only, so the answer is probably you can't :)

I enabled tcp/ip, that's where the server: "localhost" failure comes from. :P

You can enable it whole week, but localdb doesn't use tcpip, so it doesn't matter, just stick with express
